# Changing chartist text color and size

Tags: chartist.js

The font size on the charts are to small and hard to read on certain colors. Is there a way to change these attributes?

I can do this do make the whole pie red but setting color or font-size doesn't make a change:

```
.ct-series-x .ct-slice-pie {
    fill: #f05b4f
}

<div class="ct-chart ct-golden-section ct-series-x ct-slice-pie" id="chart2"></div>
```

Answer (score 17):

For anyone who comes across this - override `ct-label` in your css file:

```
.ct-label {
    font-size: 15px;
}
```